# Can´t attach eventlistener to onload event of <img>-Tag

Tags: javascript, html, events

I am wondering why I can´t attach an eventlistener to the onload event of an html image.

`<img id="imageID"  onload="doSomething();">` works perfectly,

but if I want to add a listener like

```
document.getElementById('imageID').addEventListener('onload', function(e) {
     doSomething();
     });
```

or with jQuery

```
$("imageID").on("onload", function(){
doSomething();
});
```

the event is not being catched. If I listen for a simple "click"-Event it works, but not with the "onload"-Event.

Can anybody tell my the reason for this behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't include `"on"` in the event name.

```
                              // no "on"------------v
document.getElementById('imageID').addEventListener('load', function(e) {
```

---

```
   // no "on"----v
$("#imageID").on("load", function(){
// ^----need "#"
```

Comment: Thanks, a simple and working solution! I tought the events in the html tags and js are the same, but it seems as if this is wrong (like the onload event http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_img_onload.asp)

Comment: @HartmutGrom: w3schools has a lot of information on it, but the depth and accuracy sometimes aren't brilliant (see http://w3fools.com/ for more). More reliable references for the DOM are [available from the W3C](http://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR), and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference) usually has decent information although sometimes the code samples people contribute aren't the best quality.

Answer (score 0):

There are **two** problems here.

1. You don't put "on" in the event name, as [I Hate Lazy said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13748296/157247).
2. If you're trying to hook the load event on an image that's **already on the page**, you'll have a race condition and sometimes won't see the event, because it can be "loaded" the instant that it is put on the page (if the relevant image is in cache). You have to hook load **before** the image has a `src` attribute, which typically means adding the image dynamically. Your DOM0 handler (the `onload="doSomething()"`) works because it's already attached when the image is added to the document, but anything looking the image up on the page later (`getElementById` or jQuery) may miss it.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning #2. I am changeing the src attribute dynamically by jQuery so this should be no problem

Comment: @HartmutGrom: As long as you hook the event *before* you change the `src` attribute, indeed, it should be fine. (But changing `src` and then hooking it, even in two consecutive lines of code, has the race condition even though browser-based JavaScript is single-threaded [because browsers aren't].)